# How to get list of available analyzers?

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

I'd like to add rulesets to my project following the fashion I can see in the [EFCore](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/rulesets/StyleCop.ruleset) and [MachineLearning](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/pull/5331/files) projects.

I have read through the Roslyn Analyzers doc but I didn't find a file or a method where one can get the list of avaialble analyzers. Ofcourse, I can copy and paste what I can see in the above examples, but this way I won't have a sustainable method to maintain when new rules are released.

So, the question is how can I get a list of rules in a ruleset format?

**Update**:

I opened my solution in VS which has a ruleset editor, but seemenhly it writes the rules into file randomly.

I also asked the [StylecopAnalyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/3184) guys.